# File does not exist: /home/XXX/public_html/index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I get A lot of Error message and even some time server get hang from time to time

After check we get tow kind of Error  repeated

> Using Cento7 PHP5.6.30
>
> /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log  1
>
> [Mon May 07 01:00:20.638252 2018] [:error] [pid 7023:tid
>   139835738089216] [client 141.101.77.10:19927] PHP Fatal error:  Call
>   to undefined function get_bloginfo() in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/home/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php on line 231
>   [Mon May 07 01:00:25.681306 2018] [:error] [pid 9828:tid
>   139835780052736] [client 162.158.75.246:9299] PHP Fatal error:  Call
>   to undefined function get_bloginfo() in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/home/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php on line 231
>   [Mon May 07 01:00:29.018727 2018] [:error] [pid 7122:tid
>   139835847194368] [client 141.101.77.148:18581] PHP Fatal error:  Call
>   to undefined function get_bloginfo() in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/home/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php on line 231
>   [Mon May 07 01:00:35.808256 2018] [:error] [pid 7022:tid
>   139835838801664] [client 172.68.58.85:29845] PHP Fatal error:  Call to
>   undefined function get_bloginfo() in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/home/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php on line 231
>   [Mon May 07 01:00:38.813252 2018] [:error] [pid 9828:tid
>   139835973637888] [client 141.101.76.42:33479] PHP Fatal error:  Call
>   to undefined function get_bloginfo() in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/home/wp-includes/class-wp-locale.php on line 231

2

> [Mon May 07 12:57:07.966797 2018] [:error] [pid 9930:tid
>   139835973637888] [client 162.158.74.35:36655] File does not exist:
>   /home/XXX/public_html/index.php, referer:
>   http://www.almshaheer.com/article2-460759 [Mon May 07 12:57:20.420644
>   2018] [:error] [pid 7122:tid 139835830408960] [client
>   162.158.75.12:11787] File does not exist: /home/XXX/public_html/index.php, referer:
>   http://www.almshaheer.com/article2-585530 [Mon May 07 12:57:21.005455
>   2018] [:error] [pid 9930:tid 139835746481920] [client
>   172.68.58.37:23343] File does not exist: /home/XXX/public_html/index.php, referer:
>   http://www.almshaheer.com/article2-532518 [Mon May 07 12:58:59.024635
>   2018] [:error] [pid 9828:tid 139835754874624] [client
>   172.68.58.61:28733] File does not exist: /home/XXX/public_html/index.php, referer:
>   http://www.almshaheer.com/article2-696480 [Mon May 07 13:00:28.328754
>   2018] [:error] [pid 9828:tid 139835965245184] [client
>   162.158.75.240:17833] File does not exist: /home/XXX/public_html/index.php, referer:
>   http://www.almshaheer.com/article2-192047

any help, please

Comment: do a global search for `get_bloginfo` find the file with the actual function in it. make sure it is required in, and this message will disappear

Comment: this what Written on class-wp-locale.php where exactly i should search 
  if ( 'rtl' === $this->text_direction && strpos( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '-src' ) ) {
   $this->text_direction = 'ltr';
   add_action( 'all_admin_notices', array( $this, 'rtl_src_admin_notice' ) );
  }

Comment: what? have you found the file with `function get_bloginfo (){//blah}`. require it in

Comment: In the wp-includes/functions.php file I see 2 instances of get_bloginfo:: 1-  header( "Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=" . get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) );                                                                                                   2- function wp_nonce_ays( $action ) {
 if ( 'log-out' == $action ) {
  $html = sprintf(
   /* translators: %s: site name */
   __( 'You are attempting to log out of %s' ),
   get_bloginfo( 'name' )

Comment: yup, those are just calling the same function. you need to find out which php actually defines the function, and make sure you `require_once` it

Comment: Thanks For your help if you can guide me how can i find it

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-F ? search for "function get_bloginfo" ? i have no idea what ide you use, but do a search through the files in your project for that